# Mongoose handle duplicate entries with implicit error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to check if the email or name is already in use, when i enter an already existing email and an existing name only the data from the matching email is return and no data from the name. 
req.body.email is `bob@gmail.com`
req.body.name is `hansel`

```
Account.find({$or: [ {user_email: req.body.email}, {display_name: req.body.name}]}) 
            .exec((err, user) => {
                if(err) { 
                    res.status(500).json({message: 'Internal Server Error', type: 'error'});
                }

                if(user) {
                     //  Only the data from the email match result is logged and no data for the already existing name
                     console.log(user)
                    // Response
                    res.json({
                        message: 'Account email address or Display name is already in use',
                        type: 'error'
                    })
                } else {
                    next();
                }
            });
        }
```

I am also lost how can i send a response with explicit error like 
`The display name is already in use` or `The account email address is already in use` instead of the current response which is implicit

This is from the console.log(user) it only shows the match email and not the match display name

```
[ { _id: 5ae6cd68e1f3b32237494792,
    user_email: 'bob@gmail.com',
    display_name: 'Tetris',
    registration: 2018-04-30T08:01:44.095Z,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Account schema

```
 const AccountSchema = new Schema({
        user_email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            select: false
        },
        display_name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        registration: {
            type: Date,
            required: true,
        },
    });
```

Comment: Show the schema definition for the model and the document as seen directly in the database. Use the `mongo` shell and not some GUI, and include the "text" and not a screenshot.

Comment: @NeilLunn i updated my question

Comment: Are you actually asking how to use the variable value in the returned string?

Comment: I am confuse why there is no match result for the display_name only to the email? and confuse how to know which was match so i can give explicit response. I intentionally send two entries that is currently existing in the database but the match for user is only for the email, i should have the data for hansel too right?? but only the data for the match email

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose's `.find` always return an array. If your query matches no documents it will return an empty array.

The empty array is evaluated as `true` in any condition.

```
if ( [] ) { ... } else { // will never be called }
```

That's why your code block with `next()` is never never called.

```
if( user ) {
 // ^ user is either [] or [{...},...], so it's always true
} else {
     next();
}
```

What you can do to improve your code would be to have either a `findOne` query :

```
Account.findOne( { ... } ).then( user => {

    // user is either null or { ... }

} );
```

Or simply change

```
if ( user ) { ...
```

to

```
if ( user.length > 0 ) { ...
```

About knowing which condition you have matched you can check

```
if ( user.length > 0 ) {
    res.json( {
        message : ( 
            user[0].user_email === req.body.email ? "Email" : "Display Name" 
        ) + " is already taken",
        error: true
    });
}
```

But keep in mind that this will not match a situation where the `email` and the `display name` are both used.